# Derivative of $ f(n) = n \cdot \left(1- \prod_{i=1}^n (1-\frac{1}{p_i})\right)$

Tags: derivatives, products

I'm trying to find the derivative of $f(n)$, but don't know how to evaluate the derivative of a product.

$ f(n) = n \cdot \left(1- \prod_{p<n}^n (1-\frac{1}{p})\right)$

In this case, the function contains a product of 1 minus the reciprocal of all primes up to $n$. $n$ is an integer. So far I have:

$f'(n) = 1 - (n \cdot \left( \prod_{p<n}^n (1-\frac{1}{p})\right))'$

Comment: Is $f$ defined for numbers other than integers?  presumably the product is over integers ( or primes? )

Comment: @Callus Thanks for the clarification: I've edited the question.

Comment: Why do you want to find the derivative here? What is the underlying problem you want to solve? Some context would be good.

Comment: @Winther I have two functions and would like to find which one tends to infinity at a faster rate. The one in the question is the one I don't know how to differentiate.

Comment: Ok, then as expected this is a classical [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Using derivatives is not the way to go here, I suggest trying to ask about the underlying problem instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derivative of 1 is 0 and derivative of n*constant is constant.

$\prod_{i=1}^n (1-\frac{1}{p_i})$ is constant between two consecutive integers.
So it means derivative is:
$f'(n) = 1 - (n \cdot \left( \prod_{i=1}^n (1-\frac{1}{p_i})\right))'=1-\prod_{i=1}^n (1-\frac{1}{p_i})$

It is valid for all real n except discontinuities at n integer.